# How to use useState variable in StackNavigator

Tags: react-native

I'm fetching a list of categories via the useEffect Hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(
  `/read.php?catId=${catId}`
)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    setProducts([...products, ...res.data]);
  });
}, []);
```

and store the data in a useState Hook

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
```

The {catId} I'm using in the URL is forwarded via routeName from the previous screen and I get it with getParam like that:

```
const catId = props.navigation.getParam("categoryId");
```

That's working great for inside of the functional component. The problem is, I also need props of the 'products' variable in my StackNavigator. Therefore I tried to use navigationData function of navigationOptions, once again getParam and use the find method on the products variable:

```
CategoryProductsScreen.navigationOptions = navigationData => {
  const catId = navigationData.navigation.getParam("categoryId");

  const selectedCategory = products.find(cat => cat.id === catId);

  return {
    headerTitle: selectedCategory.category_name
  };
};
```

Unfortunately the 'products' variable is not available outside of the functional component. I can't also use useEffect outside to fetch my data again, obviously.

Is there a way to get data from my useState variable in StackNavigator?
Thank you